# importing SQLiteWrapper gives error

Tags: android

i am trying to import the SQLiteWrapper but it gives an error...i am not quite sure why...
and also cant import these packages

```
import android.provider.Telephony.Sms;
import android.provider.Telephony.Threads;
import android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Inbox;
import android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Intents;
import android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Outbox;
import com.google.android.mms.MmsException;
import android.database.sqlite.SqliteWrapper
```

;
can anyone help
i am developing in eclipse on android 2.2 and running code on emulator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this blog...

```
https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/
```

you will find each and everything in detailed on how to use the hidden API's...

it helped me too...

Answer (score 0):

There is no such class in Android API package. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Perhaps you meant SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: There is in fact a `android.database.sqlite.SqliteWrapper` class, but it's hidden and not publicly available through the SDK. @kashifmehmood - what exactly do you need it for? It's just a bunch of pretty trivial `static` helper methods and junk - nothing you really need.

Comment: Yup, anything hidden is not API to be used directly

Comment: i am trying to develop an sms and mms application but i didnt know how to deal with the conversations...so i copied some code from googlesources and it contained these packages...thats why i need it...

Comment: and what about the other telephony packages...? why are they giving error in importing...?

Comment: usually the same reason, they're using functionality that's not "public" in the SDK. You can *either* build your own SDK and remove the `@hide` notations (google it) or use Java reflection to access the methods you need - both methods will let you make an app that is (potentially) a nightmare to maintain across Android versions.

Comment: that will be a long and tidy task i think...anywork around of how can i do the same work with the existing public API's...?